# Random DNS problem with NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I have a strange problem with my DNS. *Sometimes* when I boot my computer I the DNS does not work. I reboot and everything works fine.

I'm using NetworkManager and LAN - no wifi.

Today I had the DNS error again and checked a little. `journalctl -b |grep Network` showed nothing suspicous -- I compared with a *good* boot log.

After a little searching I found that `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` which is  fine and working *most* of the time.

When the DNS was not working today the file `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`  was *missing*. Why could that be?

I don't have resolveconf installed or any other network package that I'm aware of. What could cause the missing file?

Since I can't provoke the behaviour it's difficult to debug -- any suggestions what I should check when it next happens?

## Update

So I checked the NetworkManager with `nmcli device show` and it said that `eth0` was not managed (Status 10 something..)

That seemed  strange and then I found something that I had edited. Waaay back I created `/etc/network/interfaces/eth0`. So NetworkManager was not managing that connection at all and all changes in the NetworkManager were not working!

I removed `/etc/network/interfaces/eth0` and restarted NetworkManager with `systemctl reload NetworkManager.service` and now it's managing the eth0 connection:

```
> nmcli device show
GENERAL.GERÄT:                          eth0
GENERAL.TYP:                            ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         7C:05:07:3B:2E:E7
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATUS:                         100 (verbunden)
```

That might have been it. I'll wait a little and see if the error pops up again.

Comment: DHCP failing to receive a DNS Server record would result in this.  So would a misconfigured static networking item in Network Manager.  We'd need to see more details with how your system is configured.  It might be prudent to add DNS servers to your Network Manager configuration as 'additional' so you always get some DNS servers assigned.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWard I found something & updated the post. I had an additional DNS server assigned in the NetworkManager but that never worked because it wasn't managing the connection.... I'll see if the problem happens again. :)
Thank you so much for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: @ThomasWard could you change your comment about "DHCP failing" into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks. :)